# PowerApps get column names based on row data

Tags: list, sharepoint, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have a SharePoint list that I want to retrieve the column names from, based on the row value. The column names will then be matched against another SharePoint list.

In the below example I know the value of the Function column. Based on that, I want to know the column names of all columns **where the checkbox in that row is checked**.

[image]

I think I'm nearly there. I can filter the columns based on the job title and allowed values. The issue now is the "StartsWith". I want to filter the column names, but I don't know the name of the column to filter on. It has to loop trough all the columns. How do I do this?

Also I'm not sure if AllowedValues is the right way to filter the columns based on the value. Can someone verify this for me?

```
//Get job title
Set(selectedUserJobTitle, Office365Users.UserProfileV2(galleryDirectReports.Selected.userPrincipalName).jobTitle);

//Get questions starting with "Q", based on the selectedUserJobTitle and values being true
ClearCollect(colQuestions,
    Sort(
        Filter('Comp - Fuctions',
        Function.Value = selectedUserJobTitle,
        //TODO: Replace "Title" with actual column name 
        StartsWith(Title, "Q"),
        AllowedValues = true
        ), 
    Title, Ascending
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Column names are independent of the contents of any row.

Comment: too bad.. then we need to find a different solution